# Algorithm/Approach to find destination node from source node of exactly k edges in undirected graph of billion nodes without cycle

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Consider I have an adjacency list of billion of nodes structured using hash table arranged in the following manner:

key = source node 
value = hash_table { node1,  node2, node3}

The input values are from text file in the form of 
**from**,**to**
1,2
1,5
1,11
... so on

**eg.
key = '1' 

value = {'2','5','11'} 

means 1 is connected to nodes 2,5,11**

I want to know an algorithm or approach to find destination node from source node of exactly k edges in an undirected graph of billion nodes without cycle

**for eg. from node 1 I want to find node 50 only till depth 3 or till 3 edges.**

My assumption the algorithm finds 1 - 2 - 60 - 50 which is the shortest path but how would the traversing be efficient using the above adjacency list structure?
I do not want to use Hadoop/Map Reduce.

I came up with naive solution as below in Python but is not efficient. Only thing is hash table searches key in O(1) so I could just search neighbours and their billion neighbours directly for the key. The following algo takes lot of time.

1. start with source node
2. use hash table search for finding key
3. go 1 level deeper with hash table of neighbor nodes and find their values for destination nodes until node found
4. Stop if node not found on k depth

1 
  | 
{2               5                  11} 
   |                  |                      | 
{3,6,7}  {nodes}     {nodes} .... connected nodes 
  |  |  |             |                      | 
{nodes}   {nodes}    {nodes} .... million more connected nodes.

Please suggest. The algorithm above implemented similar to BFS takes more than 3 hours to search for all the possible key value relationships. Can be it be reduced with other searching method?

Comment: Why do you say your *naive* solution is not efficient? If there are millions of candidates, there is no other way than to look among those.

Comment: This seems to be simplest of the solution of how you can search for an element. I do say that its a naive solution since there might be a possibility of parallel searches or multi-threaded searches possible which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

As you've hinted, this will depend a lot on the data access characteristics of your system.  If you were restricted to single-element accesses, then you'd be truly stuck, as ***trincot*** observes.  However, if you can manage block accesses, then you have a chance of parallel operations.

However, I *think* that would be outside your control: the hash function owns the adjacency characteristics -- and, in fact, will likely "pessimize" (opposite of "optimize") that characteristic.

I do see one possible hope: use iteration instead of recursion, maintaining a list of nodes to visit.  When you place a new node on the list, get its hash value.  If you can organize the nodes clustered by location, you can perhaps do a block transfer, accessing several values in one read operation.

Comment: Hi @Prune, I do understand about maintaining the visited nodes in a list but can you please elaborate on organizing the nodes clustered by location?

Comment: One of the problems with access speed in big data is having the data spread among different blocks of storage.  If you know a little about your storage medium, you can work around this a bit.  Maintain a list of to-be-checked nodes.  Change your priority method to fetch them by their storage neighborhood, rather than detection order.

Comment: Is it related to data structures related to B Tree? Since the method you described seems to be what B Tree does if I am not wrong

Comment: No, it's not related that way.  I think you're confusing node **data** with node **address**.  A B-tree balances with respect to the data.  Your problem is with optimizing data read/write, which depends on addresses.